# Find $t_0$ and $x_0$ such that the Picard-Lindelöf Theorem hypothesis is satisfied.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I really did not understand what should be done about this problem.

> Question:
>
> Consider the equation $x'=\tan^2(t)(2x+3)^{1/3}$.
>
> i) Found $(x_0, t_0)$ such that the **Picard-Lindelöf Theorem** hypothesis for the **Initial Value Problem** is satisfied.

Some hint, please. And if possible the explanation of what I have to do.

thanks in advance.

Comment: A hint: find all those $(t_0,x_0)$ for which $\tan^2$ is continuous (or, which is the same, exists) and the function $x\mapsto(2x+3)^{1/3}$ has a continuous derivative (or, which is the same, has a derivative at all). Can you continue?

Comment: I had done this and verified that continuity is guaranteed in each interval $I_k=\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi, \frac{\pi}{2}+(k+1)\pi\right)$ (note that $tan^2$ is unlimited in $I_k$) , but the Picard-Lindelöf theorem requires that the function be limited in the interval. Im stucked in it.

Comment: For $t_0\in I_k$ you can take any closed interval $I\subset I_k$ containing $t_0$ in its interior. Regarding $x_0$, if $x_0\ne-3/2$ what can you say about the differentiability of $x\mapsto(2x+3)^{1/3}$?

Comment: $(2x+3)^{1/3}$ is differentiable for all $x_0\geq -3/2$. Is it that you ask?

Comment: And $(2x+3)^{1/3}=g(x)$ is unlimited, so I have to take a limited set in the domain of g?

Comment: For all $x_0\ne-3/2$ the function is differentiable in $x$. So, if you take such $x_0$ then you can find a compact interval $J$ containing $x_0$ in its interior such that the derivative is bounded on $J$ (it suffices to take $J$ not containing $-3/2$). Then on $I\times J$ the right-hand side of the equation satisfies all the requirements of the Picard-Lindelöf theorem.

Comment: Got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the solution to your equation $x(t)$ can also be expressed as the solution to the following integral equation:

$$x(t) = x(0) + \int_{t_0}^t \tan^2(s)(2x(s)+3)^{1/3} ds$$

The right-hand side is a nonlinear operator acting on a function $x$, and there is a unique solution if this operator has a unique fixed-point.

Therefore, the problem of figuring out when the Picard-Lindelöf theorem applies to your differential equation transforms into a question about the conditions for which the nonlinear operator above satisfies the [Banach fixed-point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem).

Comment: Should I verify when $x(0)+\int\limits_{t_0}^t tan^2(s)(2x(s)+3))^{1/3}ds$ is a contraction?

Comment: Precisely—there is a fairly concise description of when these integral operators are contraction mappings in Ziedler’s Applied Functional Analysis textbook.